# Run Django test in a docker container on Travis CI

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

[Updated]
It seems that pytest was run by updating the docker-compose.yaml as mentioned in the comment but the build didn't finish successfully. What's wrong with it?

```
WARNING: Image for service app was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-5.2.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /api
plugins: django-3.6.0
collected 0 items                                                              
============================ no tests ran in 0.01s =============================
The command "docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "pytest && flake8"" exited with 5.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I'd like to run a Django test in a docker container on Travis. However, I saw the error

> python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>   The command "docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"" exited with 2.

I felt a bit weird because I didn't see any error when I tried `docker-compose up -d` with the docker-compose.yml. Could anyone let me know what is wrong with me, please?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /api
WORKDIR /api

ADD . /api/

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip3 install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --skip-lock --system --dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/api
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

.travis.yml

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.7"

services:
  - docker

before_script: pip install docker-compose

script:
  - docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"
```

Comment: Check docker-compose.yml .  - ./app:/api. Hope it's help.

Comment: @DmitryThank you for correcting my stupid mistake!

Comment: Are you using pytest or python manage.py test? Your log mentions it's pytest. Anyway, the new error is that pytest did not find any test (`collected 0 items`) so there was nothing to do. Maybe try a `ls` or `dir` to see if you can see the tests?

Comment: @QuentinPradet I use pytest. I added an easy test case then no error appears. Thanks.